# OpenGL ES Programming Guide Particles example

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ios6

I am trying to make the particle system example given in the book OpenGL ES programming guide to compile in iOS 6 but I don't seem to be able to make it work. For reference here is the web site of the book:

http://www.opengles-book.com/

The code can be downloaded from Google Code, see instructions below:

http://code.google.com/p/opengles-book-samples/wiki/Instructions

The code is in chapter 13.

Has anyone came across this and were able to make it work in iOS 6? I had made some modifications but still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Open "Common.xcodeproj" located in "/opengles-book-samples/iPhone/Common/"
2. Select to build for device or simulator and build.
3. After Build Succeeded close the Common.xcodeproj.
4. Open Finder and from the menu Go>Go to Folder... type without quotes "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/" and find the folder called "Common-bkoronpjvpvwbxgdgxbwiukcqwaz" inside folder go to : /Build/Products/ and copy "libCommon.a" to ParticleSystem project.
5. Build&Run particle example.
6. That's it.  :)

Good luck.